# Passing html class to option in options_for_select not working Rails 2.3.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I am working on a Rails 2.3.9 application .  I need to pass a class to the options.  The way i am doing is

```
<%= select(:resporg, "hresporg_#{row_id}",options_for_select(["Item11",["Item 2", {:class => 'has-versions'}]]), {}, {:multiple => true})%>
```

**Output**

```
<select id="resporg_hresporg_1" name="resporg[hresporg_1][]" multiple="multiple">
<option value="Item11">Item11</option>
<option value="classhas-versions">Item 2</option>
</select>
```

If you check the above output the class is coming as value.  Any idea on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to manually do it because of the constraint. That [this](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) is valid for rails >= 3.0.0

In the template.html.erb

```
<select style="width:160px !important;" id="resporg_hresporg_1" name="resporg[hresporg_1][]" multiple="multiple">
      <%= opts %>
</select>
```

In the helper

```
def opts
    str = ''.html_safe
    ['Item1','Item2'].each { |val| str << content_tag(:option, val, :value => val,:class => val.eql?('Item2') ? "MyClass" : nil) }
    str.html_safe
end
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select),

```
['display','value',:class => 'option_class']
```

will produce

```
<option value="value" class="option_class">display</option>
```

So in your case, I would try this:

```
["Item 2", "Item2", :class => 'has-versions']
```

Comment: It's for >= v3.0.0.. Rails 3 it work's fine... i am working on rails 2.3.9 . I can't update rails